# Elements hidden with display:none are being added to clipboard with visible elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a JS function that copies a Div to the clipboard to be pasted into Outlook as an email, however on IE and Edge Chromium it's showing elements that are hidden with `style="display:none"` that shouldn't be shown in emails.  Is this a limitation of Chromium/IE, as this was previously working fine in Edge Legacy?

```
function copyEmail(el) {
    var body = document.body, range, sel;
    if (document.createRange && window.getSelection) {
        range = document.createRange();
        sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        try {
            range.selectNodeContents(el);
            sel.addRange(range);
        } catch (e) {
            range.selectNode(el);
            sel.addRange(range);
        }
    } else if (body.createTextRange) {
        range = body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(el);
        range.select();
    }
    document.execCommand("Copy");
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Copy Email Content" onclick="copyEmail(document.getElementById('emailcontentcopy'))">
<div id="emailcontentcopy">
<table style="display:none">
<tr><td>content not to display</td></tr>
</table>
<table style="display:block">
<tr><td>content to be shown</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: You can find hidden elements & remove them, if you can use jQuery, you can find hidden element `jQuery(element).is(":visible")`. iterate the children elements and find hidden elements & remove them.

Comment: Would that work if parts of an element are visible?  for example, the table is visible, but the third row is hidden?

Comment: Yes, jQuery would find the third row - which would not be visible - and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Emails are tricky and come with an all new set of expected behaviours and respective bug fixes.

The best solution would be to remove the table you don't want to be shown, instead of just hiding it.

If you can't remove it, try adding the Outlook attribute `mso-hide:all` to the hidden tables. For other mail servers try `display:none !important`.